# How to get the complex field data in class using Reflection (C#)

Tags: c#

I have a class as below

```
public class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {

    }
    public Orders(long OrderId, string CustomerId, 
                  int EmployeeId, double Freight, Info emp)
    {
        this.OrderID = OrderId;
        this.CustomerID = CustomerId;
        this.EmployeeID = EmployeeId;
        this.Freight = Freight;
        this.Employee = emp;
    }
    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public double Freight { get; set; }
    public Info Employee { get; set; }
}
public class Info
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Info(string Add) {
        this.Address = Add;
    }
}
```

To extract the values i am doing as below.

```
public IEnumerable PerformFiltering(
        IEnumerable dataSource, List<FilteredColumn> filteredColumns)
{
    var paramExpression = dataSource.AsQueryable().Parameter();
    Type type = dataSource.GetElementType();
    if (type == null)
    {
        Type type1 = dataSource.GetType();
        type = type1.GetElementType();
    }
    Type t = typeof(object);
    foreach (var filteredColumn in filteredColumns)
    {
        Syncfusion.Linq.FilterType filterType = (Syncfusion.Linq.FilterType)Enum.Parse(
         typeof(Syncfusion.Linq.FilterType), 
         filteredColumn.Operator.ToString(), true);

         t = type.GetProperty(filteredColumn.Field).PropertyType;
        Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    }
}
```

I got the error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Syncfusion.EJ.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Hope that you can point the line that shows the error

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you should add a `try/catch` block around the line where the exception occurs

Comment: I got the error at the "type.GetProperty(filteredColumn.Field).PropertyType" Because filteredColumn.Field holds Employee.Address

Comment: @Kalai It sounds like either `type` or `filteredColumn` does not contain anything when you see that error. You should check what values those variables hold